# how to set different NTLM versions in MAC for authentication

Tags: macos, authentication, ntlm, ntlmv2

Wanted to know if any of you aware of How to change the NTLM version in MAC OS 10.8/10.9.

I needed to set NTLM v2 in MAC,so that when i map my network device into MAC ,while authentication it should go via NTLMv2.

By default NTLMv1 is working,don't know how to change it:(..

Any help is appreciated :).